# testing on an old iPhone with no AT&T account

Tags: iphone

I have an active 3G iPhone. I do most of my testing on it.

I have an old G1 iPhone from a friend. It has a SIM but no active account. It shows "please connect to iTines" logo. When I do, iTunes asks me if I want to set up a new AT&T account or if I want to transfer one from a different phone.

I want to test my app on this older device. I wonder how I get through to it. I don't need to use cellular functionality on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer seems to be to jailbreak the thing.